# Why is this the basis for the indiscrete topology?

Tags: general-topology

Indiscrete topology only has $\{\varnothing, X\}$ where $X$ is the entire space.

I know this is probably a dumb question. Why is the basis (according to wikipedia) for this topology just $\{X\}$ instead of $\{\varnothing, X\}$?

I understand that $\{X\}$ satisfies the definition. Suppose $\mathcal{B} = \{X\}$

1. Then $\mathcal{B}$ covers $X$ - Check!
2. For all $B_1, B_2 \in \mathcal{B}, \ldots$ - Trivially satsifed since we don't have $B_1, B_2$

But how does this basis generate $\varnothing$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis, then for each open set $U$ there is a subset $\mathcal{A}\subseteq\mathcal{B}$ such that $U$ is the union of all of the elements of $\mathcal{A}$.  In this example, for $U=\emptyset$, you can just take $\mathcal{A}=\emptyset$.  The union of all the elements of $\mathcal{A}$ is the union of no sets, which is just the empty set.

By the way, you should say *a* basis, not *the* basis, since it's not the only basis for this topology: $\{\emptyset,X\}$ is also a basis.

Comment: So you mean $\varnothing$ is in the topology generated by $\mathcal{B}$ since $\varnothing$ is always a subset of $\mathcal{B}$ even though it is not an element in $\mathcal{B}$