# Why can't a base of a topology be {X}?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a non-empty set with topology $T$. Why can't a base of $T$ be $\{X\}$ ? It seems to satisfy the two conditions.

[Base of a topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/241210/base-of-a-topology)

The answer in this link implies that it can't. I would think that $\{\{a,b\}\}$ is a base as well.

It's also making one of my proofs difficult to do {given that it is a base).

Comment: It can: that’s a base for the indiscrete topology $\{X,\varnothing\}$ on $X$.

Comment: Has somebody told you it can't because it surely can.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/241210/base-of-a-topology
the answer in this link says otherwise

Comment: @user40300: Can you be more specific?  I don't see anywhere on that post that anyone said $\{X\}$ couldn't be a base.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott; a topology $\tau$ is formed from a base $\mathcal B$ by an arbitrary union of the members of the base $\mathcal B$ ;How can we generate the set $\emptyset $ here?

Comment: @EricWofsey he implied that list was complete

Comment: @BobWilson: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1826226/why-is-this-the-basis-for-the-indiscrete-topology/1826230#1826230

Comment: @Bob: $\varnothing$ is the union of the empty subset of $\{X\}$.

Comment: So i believe u guys now, thanks. I'm gonna have to ask another question then -_-

Answer (score 2):

Actually, $\{X\}$ can be a base for a topology (namely, the indiscrete topology, whose only open sets are $X$ and $\emptyset$).  In the answer you linked, Brian Scott was listing all the possible bases *for a particular topology*, namely the topology $\big\{\varnothing,\{a\},\{b\},\{a,b\}\big\}$ on the set $\{a,b\}$.  Note that $\{\{a,b\}\}$ is a base for *some* topology on $\{a,b\}$, it's just not a base for that particular topology.